# Copy whats typed into WYSIWYG editor to hidden div and submit

Tags: jquery, html, flask

I'm currently using this [bootstrap WYSIWYG editor](https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/) with a flask app.  When I try and copy the styled input to send it to my endpoint it sends a empty value.

My form input is this

```
        <form method=post action="/update/{{ state }}/{{ category }}">
          <div id="editor">
          </div>

          <input type="hidden" name="datastuff">
          <p><input type="submit" value="Update">
        </form>
```

And I'm trying to run this to submit it but it only sends a empty return

```
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#editor').keyup(function() {
             $('#datastuff').html($('#editor').html());
         });
     });
  </script>
```

Regardless of what I type into the editor it always send `ImmutableMultiDict([('datastuff', u'')])`

Here is the total html file

```
{% extends "admin_base.html" %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="container">
    <div class="hero-unit">
      <h1>{{ state }}<br/>
        <small>
          <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">{{ category }}<span class="caret"></span></button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              {% for item in form if not ( item.name == 'state' or item.name == 'csrf_token')  %}
                  <li><a href="/admin/{{ state }}/{{ item.name }}">{{ item.name }}</a></li>
              {% endfor %}
             </ul>
          </div>
        </small>
        </h1>
      <hr/>
      <div id="alerts"></div>
      <div class="btn-toolbar" data-role="editor-toolbar" data-target="#editor">
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font"><i class="icon-font"></i><b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            </ul>
          </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Font Size"><i class="icon-text-height"></i>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a data-edit="fontSize 5"><font size="5">Huge</font></a></li>
            <li><a data-edit="fontSize 3"><font size="3">Normal</font></a></li>
            <li><a data-edit="fontSize 1"><font size="1">Small</font></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn" data-edit="bold" title="Bold (Ctrl/Cmd+B)"><i class="icon-bold"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="italic" title="Italic (Ctrl/Cmd+I)"><i class="icon-italic"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="strikethrough" title="Strikethrough"><i class="icon-strikethrough"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="underline" title="Underline (Ctrl/Cmd+U)"><i class="icon-underline"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn" data-edit="insertunorderedlist" title="Bullet list"><i class="icon-list-ul"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="insertorderedlist" title="Number list"><i class="icon-list-ol"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="outdent" title="Reduce indent (Shift+Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-left"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="indent" title="Indent (Tab)"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyleft" title="Align Left (Ctrl/Cmd+L)"><i class="icon-align-left"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="justifycenter" title="Center (Ctrl/Cmd+E)"><i class="icon-align-center"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyright" title="Align Right (Ctrl/Cmd+R)"><i class="icon-align-right"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="justifyfull" title="Justify (Ctrl/Cmd+J)"><i class="icon-align-justify"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
            <a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" title="Hyperlink"><i class="icon-link"></i></a>
              <div class="dropdown-menu input-append">
                  <input class="span2" placeholder="URL" type="text" data-edit="createLink"/>
                  <button class="btn" type="button">Add</button>
          </div>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="unlink" title="Remove Hyperlink"><i class="icon-cut"></i></a>

        </div>

        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn" title="Insert picture (or just drag & drop)" id="pictureBtn"><i class="icon-picture"></i></a>
          <input type="file" data-role="magic-overlay" data-target="#pictureBtn" data-edit="insertImage" />
        </div>
        <div class="btn-group">
          <a class="btn" data-edit="undo" title="Undo (Ctrl/Cmd+Z)"><i class="icon-undo"></i></a>
          <a class="btn" data-edit="redo" title="Redo (Ctrl/Cmd+Y)"><i class="icon-repeat"></i></a>
        </div>
        <input type="text" data-edit="inserttext" id="voiceBtn" x-webkit-speech="">
      </div>


            <form method=post action="/update/{{ state }}/{{ category }}">
              <div id="editor">
              </div>

              <input type="hidden" name="datastuff" value="">
              <p><input type="submit" value="Update">
            </form>


{% endblock %}
{% block footer %}
    {{ super() }}
    <script>
    $(function(){
      function initToolbarBootstrapBindings() {
        var fonts = ['Serif', 'Sans', 'Arial', 'Arial Black', 'Courier',
              'Courier New', 'Comic Sans MS', 'Helvetica', 'Impact', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', 'Tahoma', 'Times',
              'Times New Roman', 'Verdana'],
              fontTarget = $('[title=Font]').siblings('.dropdown-menu');
        $.each(fonts, function (idx, fontName) {
            fontTarget.append($('<li><a data-edit="fontName ' + fontName +'" style="font-family:\''+ fontName +'\'">'+fontName + '</a></li>'));
        });
        $('a[title]').tooltip({container:'body'});
          $('.dropdown-menu input').click(function() {return false;})
              .change(function () {$(this).parent('.dropdown-menu').siblings('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');})
          .keydown('esc', function () {this.value='';$(this).change();});

        $('[data-role=magic-overlay]').each(function () {
          var overlay = $(this), target = $(overlay.data('target'));
          overlay.css('opacity', 0).css('position', 'absolute').offset(target.offset()).width(target.outerWidth()).height(target.outerHeight());
        });
        if ("onwebkitspeechchange"  in document.createElement("input")) {
          var editorOffset = $('#editor').offset();
          $('#voiceBtn').css('position','absolute').offset({top: editorOffset.top, left: editorOffset.left+$('#editor').innerWidth()-35});
        } else {
          $('#voiceBtn').hide();
        }
      };
      function showErrorAlert (reason, detail) {
          var msg='';
          if (reason==='unsupported-file-type') { msg = "Unsupported format " +detail; }
          else {
              console.log("error uploading file", reason, detail);
          }
          $('<div class="alert"> <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>'+
           '<strong>File upload error</strong> '+msg+' </div>').prependTo('#alerts');
      };
      initToolbarBootstrapBindings();
      $('#editor').wysiwyg({ fileUploadError: showErrorAlert} );
      window.prettyPrint && prettyPrint();
    });
    </script>
  <script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#editor').keyup(function() {
             $('#datastuff').val($('#editor').html());
         });
     });
  </script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using an `input` you need to set its `value`.

```
$('#datastuff').val($('#editor').html());
```